# Problemas de comunicación: CH341 sobre RS485 usando pyserial/screen

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, screen, pyserial

Tengo conectado en mi ordenador (Linux) dos adaptadores USB a RS485 distintos, con sus driver cargados correctamente, tal como muestra dmesg:

```
[ 4192.300959] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 4192.300979] ftdi_sio 1-3:1.0: device disconnected
[ 4195.944541] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 4196.078638] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
[ 4196.078644] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4196.078647] usb 1-3: Product: FT232R USB UART
[ 4196.078649] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: FTDI
[ 4196.081420] ftdi_sio 1-3:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[ 4196.081474] usb 1-3: Detected FT232RL
[ 4196.081806] usb 1-3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 4233.976566] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 4234.105337] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=5523
[ 4234.105342] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 4234.105882] ch341 1-2:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[ 4234.106669] usb 1-2: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

Ambos adaptadores están conectados en serie a otro dispositivo, usado para entablar una comunicación.

Desde ambos adaptadores puedo escribir hacia el dispositivo (no de forma simultanea, ya que es half-duplex), pero cuando intento escribir desde el dispositivo a través de su puerto (ttyATH0) solo al adaptador ttyUSB0 le llega la información.

Solo cuando le llegan 32 bytes o más a ttyUSB1 me imprime los últimos 32 bytes recibidos.

Estoy usando screen para leer cada puerto en mi pc:

```
screen /dev/ttyUSB0 9600 8N1

screen /dev/ttyUSB1 9600 8N1
```

Estoy usando pyserial para mandar las tramas desde mi dispositivo:

```
s = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyATH0')
s.write('\xAB\xCD')
```

He usado también serial para leer los datos recibidos y el resultado es el mismo. Siempre que le mando menos de 32 bytes, ttyUSB1 no imprime nada y su buffer (tanto de entrada cómo de salida) se encuentra vacío.

Comment: He probado con el driver de [window](http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html) y funciona todo perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado tras actualizar el Kernel

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```